# Confirm Alert not apparing

Tags: html, tags

I am not getting Confirm Alert for following code

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home", new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure that you want to logout from Single-Sign-On Portal?');" }, null)
```

Any help?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Home", new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure that you want to logout from Single-Sign-On Portal?');" }, null) %>
```

Do you have "<%=" and "%>" for the block?
If still not working, try replace this

```
new { class = "clickMe" }) 

$(".clickMe").click(function(){
  //return confirm pop
})
```